# Best way to access the hour portion of a time string? (Java)

Tags: java, time, hour, datetime-parsing, timeofday

Essentially I'm going to be reading in a time string from the user in the format `"HH:MM:SS"` in 24hr format. I want to be able to say if `HH > 12`, then assign a variable "PM" and if `HH < 12`, then assign a variable "AM".

Is splitting the string and then parsing the HH portion of that string the most efficient way to extract that segment for my purposes?

Comment: It would be slightly more efficient to convert the first one or two characters to char, and then from char to int, before you test if the int id is greater than 12.

Comment: No need to access the hour part directly. Use like `LocalTime.parse("23:56:45").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("a", Locale.ENGLISH))`. This example yields `"PM"`.